Nav2 NavThroughPoses - controller shortcuts to goal pose
Setup

Husarion Panther (diff. drive)
Jetson Orin NX (arm64) with ROS2 humble running in a docker container
Nav2 humble 1.1.16 (installed via apt)
Ouster OS0-32 LiDAR
Fixposition VRTK2

The LiDAR sensor is used for obstacle detection (costmaps), and the VRTK2 for positionning (map→odom→base_link). My nav2 configuration is similar to the GPS Localization tutorial (https://docs.nav2.org/tutorials/docs/navigation2_with_gps.html).
My setup works great with BasicNavigator.followGpsWaypoints(), but a strange behavior occurs when replacing it with BasicNavigator.goThroughPoses(). In this example, I am trying to go through 4 poses in a straight line.
Issue
When starting navigation through poses from somewhere between the first and last pose, the robot goes backwards and forwards indefinitely (see rviz2 capture).
Observing the /tranformed_global_path topic in rviz2 makes me think that the robots ocillates between ‘goal 1’ and ‘goal 4’.
I have two main interrogations here :

Why does /tranformed_global_path ocillates between “go to pose 1” and “go to pose 1, 2, 3 then 4” (entire global path) ?
When the path is “go to pose 1, 2, 3 then 4”, why does the local path aims towards the pose 4 (see rviz2 capture) ?

I guess that it has to do with the controller configuration. I am looking for insights on what controller should be used and what parameters to tune in the context of navigating through poses, with potential loops in the plan. The video was captured using DWB controller, but the same behavior is observed with RPP.
I don’t understand how controllers deal with NavThroughPoses goals. It looks like sometimes it chooses to follow the global plan, and sometimes it shortcuts to the goal pose, bypassing intermediate positions. Is it possible to avoid this shortcut behavior with existing controllers (by canceling its score for DWB ?) ?
nav2 parameters (RPP alongside commented out DWB, DWB was used for recording) :
bt_navigator:
  ros__parameters:
    global_frame: map
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    odom_topic: /fixposition/odometry_enu
    bt_loop_duration: 50
    default_server_timeout: 100
    navigators: ["navigate_to_pose", "navigate_through_poses"]
    navigate_to_pose:
      plugin: "nav2_bt_navigator::NavigateToPoseNavigator"
    navigate_through_poses:
      plugin: "nav2_bt_navigator::NavigateThroughPosesNavigator"
    # 'default_nav_through_poses_bt_xml' and 'default_nav_to_pose_bt_xml' are use defaults:
    # nav2_bt_navigator/navigate_to_pose_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml
    # nav2_bt_navigator/navigate_through_poses_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml
    # They can be set here or via a RewrittenYaml remap from a parent launch file to Nav2.
    plugin_lib_names:
      - nav2_compute_path_to_pose_action_bt_node
      - nav2_compute_path_through_poses_action_bt_node
      - nav2_smooth_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_follow_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_spin_action_bt_node
      - nav2_wait_action_bt_node
      - nav2_assisted_teleop_action_bt_node
      - nav2_back_up_action_bt_node
      - nav2_drive_on_heading_bt_node
      - nav2_clear_costmap_service_bt_node
      - nav2_is_stuck_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_reached_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_updated_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_globally_updated_goal_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_is_path_valid_condition_bt_node
      #- nav2_are_error_codes_active_condition_bt_node
      #- nav2_would_a_controller_recovery_help_condition_bt_node
      #- nav2_would_a_planner_recovery_help_condition_bt_node
      #- nav2_would_a_smoother_recovery_help_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_initial_pose_received_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_reinitialize_global_localization_service_bt_node
      - nav2_rate_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_distance_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_speed_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_truncate_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_truncate_path_local_action_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_updater_node_bt_node
      - nav2_recovery_node_bt_node
      - nav2_pipeline_sequence_bt_node
      - nav2_round_robin_node_bt_node
      - nav2_transform_available_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_time_expired_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_path_expiring_timer_condition
      - nav2_distance_traveled_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_single_trigger_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_updated_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_is_battery_low_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_navigate_through_poses_action_bt_node
      - nav2_navigate_to_pose_action_bt_node
      - nav2_remove_passed_goals_action_bt_node
      - nav2_planner_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_controller_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_checker_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_controller_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_path_longer_on_approach_bt_node
      - nav2_wait_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_spin_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_back_up_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_assisted_teleop_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_drive_on_heading_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_is_battery_charging_condition_bt_node
    error_code_names:
      - compute_path_error_code
      - follow_path_error_code

planner_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    expected_planner_frequency: 10.0
    planner_plugins: ["GridBased"]
    GridBased:
      plugin: "nav2_navfn_planner/NavfnPlanner"
      tolerance: 0.25
      use_astar: false
      allow_unknown: true

smoother_server:
  ros__parameters:
    smoother_plugins: ["simple_smoother"]
    simple_smoother:
      plugin: "nav2_smoother::SimpleSmoother"
      tolerance: 1.0e-10
      max_its: 1000
      do_refinement: True

controller_server:
  ros__parameters:
    controller_frequency: 10.0
    min_x_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    min_y_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    min_theta_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    failure_tolerance: 0.3
    progress_checker_plugins: ["progress_checker"]
    goal_checker_plugins: ["general_goal_checker"]
    controller_plugins: ["FollowPath"]

    # Progress checker parameters
    progress_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleProgressChecker"
      required_movement_radius: 0.5
      movement_time_allowance: 10.0
    general_goal_checker:
      stateful: True
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker"
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.35
      yaw_goal_tolerance: 3.15
    # DWB parameters
    FollowPath:
      # plugin: "dwb_core::DWBLocalPlanner"
      # debug_trajectory_details: True
      # min_vel_x: -0.5
      # min_vel_y: 0.0
      # max_vel_x: 0.5
      # max_vel_y: 0.0
      # max_vel_theta: 1.0
      # min_speed_xy: -0.5
      # max_speed_xy: 0.5
      # min_speed_theta: -1.0
      # acc_lim_x: 2.5
      # acc_lim_y: 0.0
      # acc_lim_theta: 3.2
      # decel_lim_x: -2.5
      # decel_lim_y: 0.0
      # decel_lim_theta: -3.2
      # vx_samples: 20
      # vy_samples: 5
      # vtheta_samples: 20
      # sim_time: 1.7
      # linear_granularity: 0.05
      # angular_granularity: 0.025
      # transform_tolerance: 0.2
      # xy_goal_tolerance: 0.35
      # trans_stopped_velocity: 0.25
      # short_circuit_trajectory_evaluation: False
      # stateful: True
      # critics: ["RotateToGoal","Oscillation","BaseObstacle","GoalAlign","PathAlign","PathDist","GoalDist"]
      # BaseObstacle.scale: 0.02
      # PathAlign.scale: 32.0
      # PathAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      # GoalAlign.scale: 24.0
      # GoalAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      # PathDist.scale: 32.0
      # GoalDist.scale: 32.0
      # RotateToGoal.scale: 32.0
      # RotateToGoal.slowing_factor: 5.0
      # RotateToGoal.lookahead_time: -1.0

      plugin: "nav2_regulated_pure_pursuit_controller::RegulatedPurePursuitController"
      desired_linear_vel: 0.5
      lookahead_dist: 0.9
      min_lookahead_dist: 0.3
      max_lookahead_dist: 1.2
      lookahead_time: 1.5
      rotate_to_heading_angular_vel: 2.5
      transform_tolerance: 0.1
      use_velocity_scaled_lookahead_dist: false
      min_approach_linear_velocity: 0.05
      approach_velocity_scaling_dist: 0.9
      use_collision_detection: false
      max_allowed_time_to_collision_up_to_carrot: 1.0
      use_regulated_linear_velocity_scaling: true
      use_fixed_curvature_lookahead: false
      curvature_lookahead_dist: 0.5
      use_cost_regulated_linear_velocity_scaling: false
      regulated_linear_scaling_min_radius: 0.9
      regulated_linear_scaling_min_speed: 0.25
      use_rotate_to_heading: true
      allow_reversing: false
      rotate_to_heading_min_angle: 0.785
      max_angular_accel: 3.2  
      max_robot_pose_search_dist: 10.0

behavior_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: false
    local_costmap_topic: local_costmap/costmap_raw
    global_costmap_topic: global_costmap/costmap_raw
    local_footprint_topic: local_costmap/published_footprint
    global_footprint_topic: global_costmap/published_footprint
    cycle_frequency: 10.0
    behavior_plugins: ["spin", "backup", "drive_on_heading", "assisted_teleop", "wait"]
    spin:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/Spin"
    backup:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/BackUp"
    drive_on_heading:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/DriveOnHeading"
    wait:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/Wait"
    assisted_teleop:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/AssistedTeleop"
    local_frame: odom
    global_frame: map
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    transform_tolerance: 0.2
    simulate_ahead_time: 2.0
    max_rotational_vel: 1.0
    min_rotational_vel: 0.4
    rotational_acc_lim: 3.2

local_costmap:
  local_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False
      update_frequency: 15.0
      publish_frequency: 15.0
      global_frame: odom
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      rolling_window: True
      width: 6
      height: 6
      resolution: 0.1
      #robot_radius: 0.4
      footprint: "[ [-0.41, -0.45], [-0.41, 0.45], [0.41, 0.45], [0.41, -0.45] ]"
      plugins: ["voxel_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 1.5
        inflation_radius: 2.0
      voxel_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"
        enabled: True
        publish_voxel_map: True
        origin_z: 0.0
        z_resolution: 0.1
        z_voxels: 20
        max_obstacle_height: 1.6
        mark_threshold: 0
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /ouster/points
          max_obstacle_height: 0.7
          min_obstacle_height: -0.35
          clearing: True
          marking: True

          data_type: "PointCloud2"
          raytrace_max_range: 5.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 5.0
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
      always_send_full_costmap: True

global_costmap:
  global_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False
      update_frequency: 10.0
      publish_frequency: 10.0
      global_frame: map
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      #robot_radius: 0.4
      footprint: "[ [-0.41, -0.43], [-0.41, 0.43], [0.41, 0.43], [0.41, -0.43] ]"
      resolution: 0.1
      # When using GPS navigation you will potentially traverse huge environments which are not practical to
      # fit on a big static costmap. Thus it is recommended to use a rolling global costmap large enough to 
      # contain each pair of successive waypoints. See: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/issues/2174
      rolling_window: True
      width: 50
      height: 50
      track_unknown_space: true
      # no static map
      plugins: ["voxel_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 1.5
        inflation_radius: 2.0
      voxel_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"
        enabled: True
        publish_voxel_map: True
        origin_z: 0.0
        z_resolution: 0.1
        z_voxels: 20
        max_obstacle_height: 1.6
        mark_threshold: 0
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /ouster/points
          max_obstacle_height: 0.7
          min_obstacle_height: -0.35
          clearing: True
          marking: True

          data_type: "PointCloud2"
          raytrace_max_range: 10.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 10.0
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
      always_send_full_costmap: True

waypoint_follower:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    loop_rate: 20
    stop_on_failure: false
    waypoint_task_executor_plugin: "wait_at_waypoint"
    wait_at_waypoint:
      plugin: "nav2_waypoint_follower::WaitAtWaypoint"
      enabled: True
      waypoint_pause_duration: 200

velocity_smoother:
  ros__parameters:
    smoothing_frequency: 20.0
    scale_velocities: False
    feedback: "OPEN_LOOP"
    max_velocity: [0.5, 0.0, 0.5]
    min_velocity: [-0.5, 0.0, -0.5]
    max_accel: [2.5, 0.0, 3.2]
    max_decel: [-2.5, 0.0, -3.2]
    odom_topic: "odom"
    odom_duration: 0.1
    deadband_velocity: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    velocity_timeout: 1.0

